# Convolving a feature map with itself

Tags: tensorflow

I use TensorFlow 1.12

I would like to take a batch of feature maps `[B,H,W,C]`, and would like to convolve each channel with itself.

This probably is possible with `tf.map_fn`, but I would like to keep these operations as vectorized as possible.

What is the best vectorized way of achieving it ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'convolve with itself'? Is the feature map your kernel? Then is would be just a point-wise product and afterwards a `tf.reduce_sum`. Note here that `tf.map_fn` is not able to propagate gradients and thus you can not use it inside a NN that should be optimized.

Comment: 1. Yes. I want each channel of a feature map to be its corresponding kernel.
2. I would like to pad the feature map (not the corresponding filter), so that the output feature map is the same size as the featuer map.

It is not my objective to backpropagate.

Answer (score 0):

Each channel is an image. Convolving an image with another, itself in this case, is most efficiently implemented in the Fourier domain using the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). It states that a convolution of an image with another is the same as the inverse Fourier transform of the dot product of their Fourier transforms. Breaking that into steps:

1. Optionally, [pad the images with zeros](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/741/why-should-i-zero-pad-a-signal-before-taking-the-fourier-transform)
2. [Fourier transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/spectral/fft2d) both images.
3. Calculate the dot product of the Fourier transforms.
4. [Inverse Fourier transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/spectral/ifft2d).

Both images being the same is a special case.